# Saving Return Data from a http request in a service to local storage and checking/loading it on app start in ionic

Tags: angularjs, http, caching, ionic-framework, local-storage

I am making an Ionic app and I am utilizing $http service to pull in a page data from a server in JSON format through an API. My factory looks like this:

```
 app.factory('FaqHiveData', function ($http, $q, $timeout, $log, $stateParams, $ionicLoading) {
    var faqdata = [];
    $ionicLoading.show();

return {
    all: function () {
        var dfd = $q.defer();
        $http.get("http://hive.squaresoftng.com/api/get/faq/")//, {cache: true}
        .then(function (response) {
            faqdata = response.data;
            dfd.resolve(faqdata);
        }).finally(function(){
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        });
        return dfd.promise;
    }
};
});
```

in app.js, i am using a resolve function in my app.config for each state

```
.state('app.faq', {
        url: '/faq',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/faq.html',
                controller: 'FaqCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    faqdata: function (FaqHiveData) {
                      return FaqHiveData.all();
                    }
                  }
            }
        }
    })
```

i also enable cache in my app.config

```
// enable http caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;
```

then i use the return data in my controller from the scope

```
app.controller('FaqCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $timeout, $log, faqdata, ionicMaterialInk) {

    $scope.faqdata = faqdata;
    //add ref to other needed value in the scope.faqdata
    $scope.faqs = $scope.faqdata.faqs;
});
```

this works for accessing the data in my views, but i want to set this returned data to local storage in order to have access to it when the app starts or there is no connection.

Comment: how about just doing what you want? The localStorage API is pretty simple to use:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage